# access docker VM in private network (docker-machine)

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have a server in my private network and on this server there is a VM running with docker installed.

What's the "docker-way" to access this VM?

I thought about docker-machine but as I understand I can only create and manage *new* machines - and also only in VirtualBox or Cloud Providers (AWS, Azure), but not a VM in a private network.

I think it should be possible to use `@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env <VM-Name>') DO @%i` which "connects" me to a machine which I created via docker-machine - but how can I define a VM that already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this just with Docker, you don't need Docker Machine. The CLI on your local machine can connect to a remote Docker Engine. Set the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable on your client to your VM's host address:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://[IP-ADDRESS]:2375  #Linux/Mac
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://[IP-ADDRESS]:2375 #Windows
```

Now when you run `docker` commands, they'll execute on the VM. When you're done with the remote connection, use `unset DOCKER_HOST` or `set DOCKER_HOST=` to remove the variable, and your local client will connect your local engine.

Comment: But what about authentication?

Comment: when I do so, I get `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`.

Comment: You need to explicitly allow remote access to your Docker Engine - on a trusted network you can start the daemon with option `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` which uses unencrypted TCP.  Or you can set up the host for [HTTPS access](https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/security/https/).